# css before not working in IE 8

Tags: css, wicket

I am using wicket framework and overriding `appendOptionHtml` of `ListMultipleChoice` 
to generate below select tag and using CSS `:before` to place red * before option text
it is working fine in FF but not in IE.

CSS:

```
.required:before {
    content: "*";
    color: #8B2942;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<select>
 <option class="required" value="0">test1</option>
 <option class="required" value="1">test2</option>
 <option class="required" value="2">test3</option>
</select>
```

Can anyone please help or any other way to put red asterisk to my option text?
I have tried all DOCTYPE still not working.

Answer (score 2):

The required notice belongs on the label of the select field, not the options. eg:

```
.required{color:#8B2942}

<label for="myselect"><span class="required">*</span> Title: </label>
<select id="myselect" name="myselect">
    <option value="1">test1/option>
    <option value="2">test2</option>
    <option value="3">test3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes to ^. Required should go on the label. In addition, you might help screenreaders out like this: `<label for="myselect" title="Required" aria-required="true"><span class="required">*</span> Title: </label>`

Comment: thanks for the reply ..However still i am having the same issue here the problem is i want to add red asterick before the option text i want the above code                                                  <option value="1"> [ASTERICK IN RED COLOR]test1/option>

Comment: one more point i found that option tag is not supporting css before in IE8

Comment: It doesn't make sense for an option to be required. It's the select field that would be required, then the user selects an option.

Comment: Ohh it seems i was not clear with my question ..let me try to put in another way ... well i am using wicket and i am having two ListMultipleChoice component [1]  > [2]  . Here in the 2nd list[2] i have few options that i have to show as required field which can never be transfer from one list to another (from 2 to 1)  .